# Matlab 2015a compiler setup file not working

Tags: c++, matlab, sdk, windows-10

I have **Matlab 2015a** on **windows 10** and I'm trying to install a c/c++ compiler Microsoft windows SDK 7.1 which requires **.NET FRAMEWORK 4**. I have .NET FRAMEWORK 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6 already installed, but the SDK installer still asking for .NET FRAMEWORK 4 but i can't install it because it says it is already installed. Please Help

Comment: I think this is a question for superuser and not for stackoverflow.